# Update AWS EB application on S3 file change

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am relatively new to AWS and so far I have an EB application pulling data from an object in an S3 bucket. I update this object in S3 every day and I want the EB application to refresh with the new data every time the S3 file changes but it seems not to be doing that (it still reflects old data from file)?

In my S3 bucket, I am just storing a single .csv file which I am reading from my EB application (python based so using boto3).

Here is the code I use to read the .csv file from S3 in my EB application:

```
client = boto3.client("s3")
bucket_name = "bucket-name"
file_name = "file_name.csv"
object_key = file_name
csv_obj = self.client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_key)
body = csv_obj["Body"]
csv_string = body.read().decode("utf-8")
raw_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_string))
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Do you want to pull a deployable from S3 and update the running instance within beanstalk or is some code of yours that is running inside beanstalk supposed to retrieve that s3 data and e.g. return it when asked for it? If so: what is your current code for that? What data pulls what at what point and in what way do you want what exactly to change? ^^

Comment: Set up a notification on the bucket and listen on the target queue / topic.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a link that describes this process?

Comment: Yes, I had that link ready but forgot to add it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-how-to-event-types-and-destinations.html